# NTFS symlinks in linux

Tags: linux, ntfs, symbolic-link

I have an NTFS formatted drive (from a previous windows installation) and it contains some symlinks (reparse points),

For some reason, I can't do anything with these symlinks: I can't go to where they link to, I can't even delete them.

I guess the reason has to be that the link contained `C:\` as a part of it.

How can I deal with this issue?

#### UPDATE:

To clarify, these links are junctions/reparse points.

For instance, I had `C:\progs` be a symlink to `C:\Program Files`

If I try to remove it, I get:

```
$ rm /media/disk/progs/ -rf
rm: cannot remove directory `/media/disk/progs': Operation not supported
```

I actually removed `/media/disk/Program Files/` anyway.

#### UPDATE2:

My system is linux mint (ubuntu based)

Comment: are the "links" named something like "foo.lnk" ?

Comment: no, that would be a shortcut

Comment: Symlinks and reparse points aren't exactly the same thing. (NTFS symlinks work exactly as Unix ones.)

Comment: Yea, I just didn't want people to think that I'm an idiot who thinks shortcuts and symlinks are the same.

Comment: and i just wanted to clarify that you are not an idiot who thinks shortcuts are the same as symlinks. it's just not that common to create such reparse points in windows ...

Comment: sure, no problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As explained in the [Questions & Answers](http://www.ntfs-3g.org/support.html#filedelete) of the NTFS-3G support section, deleting a Reparse Point is not fully supported by the NTFG-3G driver. You might have to install the Advanced NTFS-3G driver:

> **Why do I get an "Operation not supported" message when deleting a file?**
>
> The NTFS-3G 1.5012 driver has solved this issue, *or you're trying to delete an NTFS [Reparse Point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365503(VS.85).aspx) which is not fully supported yet in Stable NTFS-3G, only in the [Advanced NTFS-3G](http://pagesperso-orange.fr/b.andre/advanced-ntfs-3g.html) version of the driver*.

I can't provide more specific guidance without more informations on your Linux distribution, version, etc.

Comment: LinuxMint 7, based on Ubuntu 9.04

Comment: Awesome, I downloaded the "executable for knoppix", version, and it worked! I just extracted it somewhere and did what the README said.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: 2 of the 3 links in your post broke

Answer (score 0):

Try using [ntfs3g](http://www.ntfs-3g.org/index.html). You may have to create a file [`/.NTFS-3G`](http://pagesperso-orange.fr/b.andre/junctions.html) if you have symlinks to a different drive letter.

Comment: What exactly should I try?

Comment: If he's using a mainstream distro (Ubuntu, Fedora, SUSE...) then it has the NTFS-3G driver installed by default.