# How to get OSX/Linux to recognize Windows Symlinks

Tags: linux, windows, macos, symbolic-link

When connecting to a Windows share through OSX or Linux, symlinks are not properly recognized. They either appear as aliases with no target, or as folders with no permissions to access.

At this point is there still no way to have the Windows symlinks readable by other operating systems?

Comment: This might help you understand the problem http://superuser.com/questions/43297/ntfs-symlinks-in-linux?rq=1

Comment: Hmmm... seems they are suggesting installing this NTFS-3G package. I was hoping there was a less hacked together method for doing this at this point as that discussion is over 4 years old :)

Comment: Verify when the NTFS Linux drivers were last updated, my guess, they have not. Sometimes answers are not what you want to hear, drivers shouldn't change, and NTFS is still and will always be unofficial in Linux and OS X ( unless Apple decides otherwise ).

Comment: @Ramhound So you're saying it should just work with current drivers?

Comment: The answer I linked indicates you have to install the `Advanced NTFS-3G` drivers.  Have you tried that suggestion?  **I won't proceed unless you have.**  I should point out the `NTFS-3G` is the stable drive, your already using it, and it does not support what you want.

Comment: Sorry it's beyond my understand as to how to take that source and get to work on OSX/CentOS

Comment: First it won't work on `OS X`.  Second you have to replace the driver.  There should be a readme that comes with the source with installation instructions.  I can't view the source because the domain is blocked at my current location.